How to prove $\sum_{n=c}^{\infty}\binom{n}{c}\phi^c(1-\phi)^{n-c}\cdot\frac{e^{-s}s^n}{n!}=\frac{e^{-s\phi}(s\phi)^c}{c!}$?
This formula came from a probability and statistics book: Probability Theory: The Logic of Science by Edwin Jaynes.
$$\sum_{n=c}^{\infty}\binom{n}{c}\phi^c(1-\phi)^{n-c}\cdot\frac{e^{-s}s^n}{n!}=\frac{e^{-s\phi}(s\phi)^c}{c!}$$
This problem is about finding the probability of a Geiger counter getting $c$ clicks, given $n$ number of particles greater than passes through it; the strength of the beam is $s$, and the Poisson part on the right is the formula for calculating the probability of $n$ particles passing through the counter, and $\phi$ is the efficiency of the counter. It is the probability that the Geiger counter will register a click given a particle goes through it. The knowns are $\phi$ and $s$, and the unknowns are $n$ and $c$.
Proving this formula has me stumped.
Edit.
I tried changing the binomial part of the formula into a Poisson, but that didn't work. Then, I tried changing the Poisson part of the formula back into a binomial. Again, it got nowhere. It is not my homework. I am a 50+ year old widower and high school physics teacher who does math in his spare time.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Could it be wrong? Could it be your homework? What have you tried?

I tried changing the binomial part of the formula into a Poisson, but that didn't work. Then, I tried changing the Poisson part of the formula back into a binomial. Again, it got nowhere. No, it is not my homework. I am a 50+ year old widower and high school physics teacher who does math in his spare time.

Hint:$$e^{s(1-\phi)}=\sum_{n=c}^\infty\frac{[s(1-\phi)]^{n-c}}{(n-c)!}.$$
